# Accessing Controller variable in View MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have started to use MVC  and i have set up a simple project that has a controller than returns a value from entity FrameWork. I have a controller for the index page which visual studio setup as default in its template.

I am hoping that this value will be returned to the index page of the website.

Controller code

```
 MISEntities db = new MISEntities();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Real Time Production";

        var scrap = from r in db.tbl_dppIT
                        select r.CastGood; 

        return View(scrap);
    }
```

How do i access the var scrap using razor?
I have looked at the viewbag method and other razor syntax but cant seem to find how i access this item.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just because the controller variable is declared using the `var` keyword doesn't mean it doesn't have a type. Rather, this tells C# that the type should be inferred by its context (in this case, an `IEnumerable<T>` of whatever type `tbl_dppIT.CastGood` is).

So, the other three answers are partly correct, you need to define the type of model being passed into the View via the razor keyword `@model` as noted by the other answers:

```
// In your view Razor:
@model IEnumerable</* type of CastGood */>
```

There is an alternative to the three answers already specified, and that is sticking the `scrap` variable into the `ViewBag` in your controller:

```
ViewBag.Scrap = scrap;
```

When you access the expando property `Scrap` from the `ViewBag` in the view, it will be a dynamic object, so you won't get the aid of IntelliSense. But, it is another way, just so that you know all the possibilities.

**UPDATE:**

Based on your comments below, it looks like if CastGood is a database column that is allowed to be null and whose type is `int`, then you'd want:

```
@model IEnumerable<int?>
```

HTH.

Comment: When i add the following "@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.tbl_dppIT>" i get this error'The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MvcApplication1.Models.tbl_dppIT]'.

Comment: hmm, try `@model MvcApplication1.Models.tbl_dppIT`. That may already be an `IEnumerable<T>` from EF (or whatever ORM you're using).

Comment: still getting the error :/The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MvcApplication1.Models.tbl_dppIT'.

Comment: OK, the simple answer is, you need to know the .Net type being returned from your query when you set the `scrap` variable in your controller. Whatever that type is, that's what type your `@model` needs to be. Either that, or use the `ViewBag`--but again, without IntelliSense support since it's a `dynamic`.

Comment: Looking at your code, I'd say your `@model` should be of type `IEnumerable</* type of CastGood /*>` since that's what's being returned by the LINQ query setting `scrap` in your controller. So, if `CastGood` is an `int`, then `IEnumerable<int>`. If `CastGood` is a concrete object, then `IEnumerable<CastGood>`, etc.

Comment: I have passed this System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]]
But its looking for this
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32]

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the type of the variable scrap as the model inside the View using the `@model` keyword.

```
// View.cshtml

@model IEnumerable<Namespace.ScrapType>

@foreach(var item in Model) {
    <p>@item.SomeProperty</p>
}
```

See [Part 3: Views and ViewModels](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3) of the MVC Music Store example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to strongly type your view and it will available as the Model instance.

```
@model IEumerable<MyType>

@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    @*do something with it *@
}
```